# C# Interop: How to iterate through citations in Word doc?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'd like to iterate through all the citations in a Word document that I'm adding using the ribbon's "Citations & Bibliography >> Insert Citation" but am not finding where they're located. E.g., to iterate through Fields I

```
foreach (Field f in document.Fields)
```

but a citation isn't a field and there's not Document.Citations object?

Comment: I think you are looking for [TablesOfAuthorities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.tablesofauthorities?view=word-pia)

Comment: @maccettura thanks. I should have been clearer in my OP. I'm not adding the citation through "Table of Authorities > Mark Citation", I'm using "Citations & Bibliography > Insert Citation". As a result, Document.TablesOfAuthorities.Count is returning 0. (I'll update my OP)

Comment: Maybe [Bibliography.Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.bibliography.sources?view=word-pia) then?

Comment: @maaccettura, nope. Document.Bibliography.Sources.Count also returns 0.

Comment: @maccettura. Sorry, should have given more detail. Bibliograph.Sources is giving me the list of sources, not the list of citations to these sources, which is what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have zero experience with the Interop library, but based on your comments and some googling I think you need to check the `Type` of the `Field` object.  The enum is called [WdFieldType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdfieldtype?view=word-pia), and the specific value is `WdFieldType.wdFieldCitation` which according to the docs indicates a "Citation field".  You can employ some basic filtering using LINQ:

```
foreach(Field f in document.Fields.Where(x => x.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldCitation))
{
    // Do something with citation fields
}
```